# How to get static props or public file (Image) from api/route file?

Tags: next.js, serverless, vercel

So I want to create a watermark for an image from a client, and I'm saving the watermark image in a public directory. I'm using nextjs 13 app route and there's no documentation about this except for pages route

Anyone can help me with this?

```
/// src/app/api/route.ts

export async function handleImage(file: File) {
  try {
    const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes);
    const production = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRODUCTION as string;
    let path: string;

    if (production === "true") {
      path = join("/", "tmp", file.name);
    } else {
      path = join("./public", "tmp", file.name);
    }

    const pathWM = join(process.cwd(), "/public/wm.png");

    const watermark = await sharp(buffer)
      .composite([{ input: await readFile(pathWM), top: 50, left: 50 }])  //the problem is here!!
      .png({ quality: 80 })
      .toBuffer();
    await writeFile(path, watermark);

    const ImgTwitterId = await rwClient.v1.uploadMedia(path);
    const response = { path: path, mediaId: ImgTwitterId };

    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to have the image in a non public directory like assets or something then the server will be able to access it

Comment: @Matt can you give me an example folder structure that you mean and how can i get the image in the route.ts file ?

Comment: The nextjs routes cannot access public images as its run on the server. So my suggestion would be to create a new folder ie assets, it can be in the route of your project. Then add the images you need to reach within that assets folder. You can access them the same way you currently do.